# Is finiteness of automorphism groups a birational question?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, automorphism-groups

Let $X$ be a proper variety over $\mathbb{C}$ and let $Y\to X$ be a proper birational surjective morphism.

Is $Aut(X)$ finite if and only if $Aut(Y)$ is finite?

The answer is no. Indeed, $\mathbb{P}^2$ has infinite automorphism group, but $\mathbb{P}^2$ blown up in six points in general position has finite automorphism group.

So my real question is:

> > Assume $Aut(Y)$ is finite. Under what additional assumptions is $Aut(X)$ finite?

Comment: If $Y$ is a canonical birational model of $X$ like a minimal model of a general type variety then this implication holds.

Comment: @WillSawin Ok. What if $Y$ is a minimal model of $X$, and $Y$ is of Kodaira dimension $\geq 0$?

Comment: I suspect that if $X$ is any variety whatsoever for which $Aut(X)$ is infinite, you can blow up a few random points (the number of points depends on $X$, of course) and you get a variety for which $Aut(Y)$ is finite.

Comment: @Elliot In the case that $Y$ is minimal, maybe you get the statement for $X$, but this is typically something pretty singular -- is that the kind of thing you are interested in?

Comment: @Mark I am inclined to agree with your first comment, but I'm not completely sure how to prove this...Also, concerning your second comment: yes, that's the kind of thing I am actually interested in.